# Exponent Recursion implementation

Tags: recursion

I want to implement this recursive formula:

[image]

"j" is imaginary symbol (i.e. j = I = Sqrt[-1]); I have written my code as:

```
expR[0, theta_] := Exp[0] = 1.;
expR[m_, theta_] := Exp[-I m theta] = Exp[-I (m - 1) theta] Exp[-I theta];
```

but it not works, for example my thetalist could be:

```
thetalist = RandomReal[2., {5}]  (*{1.36386, 0.720838, 0.504584, 0.154796, 1.83031}*)
```

but I always got warning when testing something for example:

```
expR[20, thetalist]
```

> Set::write: Tag Exp in Exp[{0. -27.2773 I,0. -14.4168 I,0. -10.0917 I,0. -3.09593 I,0. -36.6061 I}] is Protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thetalist = {1.36386, 0.720838, 0.504584, 0.154796, 1.83031};
```

Method 1:

```
Clear[expR]

expR[0, theta_] = 1;

expR[m_Integer?Positive, theta_] := 
 expR[m, theta] = expR[m - 1, theta]*Exp[-I*theta]

list11 = expR[#, theta] & /@ Range[0, 20];

list11[[1 ;; 5]]

(* {1, E^(-I theta), E^(-2 I theta), E^(-3 I theta), E^(-4 I theta)} *)
```

More generally,

```
FindSequenceFunction[list11[[2 ;; 10]], m] // PowerExpand

(* E^(-I m theta) *)

list12 = expR[20, thetalist]

(* {-0.542712 - 0.839919 I, -0.275965 - 0.961168 I, -0.785742 + 
  0.618555 I, -0.998957 - 0.0456568 I, 0.459902 + 0.88797 I} *)

list12 == Exp[-I 20 thetalist]

(* True *)
```

Method 2 : Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[expR]

expR[m_, theta_] = 
 expR[m, theta] /. 
   RSolve[{expR[0, theta] == 1, 
      expR[m, theta] == expR[m - 1, theta]*Exp[-I*theta]}, 
     expR[m, theta], {m, theta}][[1]] // PowerExpand

(* E^(-I m theta) *)
```

which is identical to the result from [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) above

```
list21 = expR[#, theta] & /@ Range[0, 20];

list22 = expR[20, thetalist]

(* {-0.542712 - 0.839919 I, -0.275965 - 0.961168 I, -0.785742 + 
  0.618555 I, -0.998957 - 0.0456568 I, 0.459902 + 0.88797 I} *)

list22 == Exp[-I 20 thetalist]

(* True *)
```

Verifying that both methods are equivalent for nonnegative, integer `m`

```
list11 == list21

(* True *)

list12 == list22

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!